# sort order explanation

Tags: terminal, osx, sort

Giving a lot of files, `sort -n` gives me this result:

```
f1.txt
f10.txt
f2.txt
```

which doesn't seem right to me. What is the explanation?

Can I get this by default:

```
f1.txt
f2.txt
f10.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to use rather

```
sort -V data.txt
```

`-V` stands for "version sort" and it basically handles correctly both alphabetical and numerical characters, so that if you would have more files, say:

```
f1.txt
f10.txt
f2.txt
a1.txt
a10.txt
a2.txt
```

then `sort -V` will give you

```
a1.txt
a2.txt
a10.txt
f1.txt
f2.txt
f10.txt
```

whereas `sort -k 1.2n` or `sort -n -k 1.2`:

```
a1.txt
f1.txt
a2.txt
f2.txt
a10.txt
f10.txt
```

Comment: You're liitle bit faster. ;) Add a long option `--version-sort`.

Comment: OS X `sort` (which the tags imply the asker is using) [does not support version sorting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sort.1.html), so this won't work for them in particular.

Answer (score 4):

Because your data lines don't *start* with a number, the `-n`umeric sort treats them as non-numbers (and so leaves them where they are). As soon as it stops being possible to interpret the data as a number `-n` stops caring. You need to use the [`-k`eyed sort option](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sort.1.html):

```
sort -k 1.2n data.txt
```

That sorts with a key defined by the first field, starting at the second character, using numeric comparison from that point onwards.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it doesn't leave them as they are. They are considered as 0. And then, the last resort sort, sorts them by byte value. So for instance `" a"`, `"0"`, and `"a"` have all value 0, but the last resort sort will sort them in that order.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Are they considered as 0? I think it's compare byte by byte.

Comment: @cuonglm, for all the lines that sort the same (with `-n`, that have the same numerical value), the last-resort sort sorts them byte by byte. That's what I said. `0` and `a` sort the same numerically but `a` sorts after  `0` because of byte value. `a` and `*a` sort after `-1` (even though `*` sorts before `-` by byte value) because their value is 0. That's specified by POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) with `-n` option using [strnumcmp()](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/lib/strnumcmp.c) which does not do [numeric conversions (See numcompare() function)](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/lib/strnumcmp-in.h). This's purely string comparison.

When your key field does not start with a number, the last resort sort sorts byte by byte, you will get the result alphabetic order base on your locale.

Example:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort -n test.txt
f10.txt
f1.txt
f2.txt

$ LC_ALL=C sort -n test.txt
f1.txt
f10.txt
f2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> sort -n -t . -k 1.2 file
f1.txt
f2.txt
f10.txt
```

Works even without the `-t .`.

Answer (score 1):

If using `zsh`, you can sort the list numerically with:

```
printf '%s\n' *.txt(n)
```

That's similar to GNU `sort -v` or GNU `ls`'s `-v` sorting:

```
ls -vd -- *.txt
```

That sorts `f2` before `f10`, but `g1` after `f2`.

To sort a list stored in a `zsh` array (as opposed to files in the current directory with globbing):

```
files=(
  f1.txt
  f10.txt
  f2.txt
)
printf '%s\n' ${(n)files}
```